# Decrypting message as MSB in regev scheme

Tags: public-key, homomorphic-encryption, lwe

I was watching this [FHE video](https://simons.berkeley.edu/talks/shai-halevi-2015-05-18a) and it define Regev encryption scheme as fallow :

**kyegen:**

- sk : choose $t = (1,s)^t \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{n+1}$
- pk = $A \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{m*(n+1)}$ random except $[A * t]_q$  small

**Enc:** for random $r \in \{0,1\}^m $ output and $\mu \in\{0,1\}$

- $c \leftarrow (\mu,0,...,0).\frac{q}{2} + r.A$

**Dec :** compute
$$\langle c,t\rangle =  \mu.\frac{q}{2} + r.A.t = \mu.\frac{q}{2} + \; small \; (mod \; q)$$

- **Decrypt $\mu$ as MSB$([\langle c,t \rangle]_q)$**

But i can not understand how decryption works? what i think is  for example for $q = 8$ if $[\langle c,t \rangle]_q \in [2,6)$ message is 1 and if $[\langle c,t \rangle]_q \in [6,8) \cup [0,2)$ message is 0 (if absolute value of small in $\langle c,t\rangle$ be less thatn $q/4$). I cant understand how the message would be **MSB**$([\langle c,t \rangle]_q)$ ? for example if we use 3 bits for each number MSb of both 0 and 3 would be 0.

**Edit**

responding to @kelalaka answer. beside $q$ being odd which is important but not very much what made me confused at first place was [this section of Regev's paper](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Eregev/papers/lwesurvey.pdf#section.4). I think what you said is true when **"small"** bounded like $0<= small < q/2$. for example for $q = 7$ we have something like
$$000\\001\\010\\\\011\\---------\\100\\101\\110$$
and what i said when $-q/4<= small < q/4$ and depends on error distribution you choose at first place. but still not sure.

**Edit 2 :** actually it was kinda a silly question. for future reference if somebody(with low probability) came across this question. [Homomorphic Encryption](https://shaih.github.io/pubs/he-chapter.pdf) is a good paper from SHai Halevi, the guy in the video. and at secction 2.1    Notations and Basic Definitions you can find definition of $[\;\;]_q$ and much more.

Comment: Article says that `Hence we see that
2a decryption error occurs only if the sum of the error terms over all S is greater than q/4`. Updated the answer, too.

Comment: It also says that, with standard deviation, the probability of $e > q/4$ is negligible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors on the definition of the Regev's Scheme

- Keygen($1^n$):

  - sk : choose $t = (1,s)^t \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{n}$ where $q$ is an prime between $n^2$ and $2n^2$
  - pk = $B \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{m\times n}$ random except $[B \times t]_q$  "small"
- $Encryption(B,\mu \in \{0,1\}$:  For random $r \in \{0,1\}^m $ output and $\mu \in\{0,1\}$
  $$c \leftarrow (\mu,0,...,0) \cdot \frac{q}{2} + r \times B$$
- $Decrypt(c,t)$ : Compute

$$\langle c,t\rangle =  \mu \cdot \frac{q}{2} + r \times B \times t = \mu \cdot \frac{q}{2} + \text{ "small"} \pmod q$$

- Recover $\mu$ as MSB$([\langle c,t \rangle]_q)$

Details

- **the secret key** is a $n$ dimensional vector in $\mathbb{Z}_q^{n}$ where the first component is $1$
- **The public key** is a matrix except that when you multiply with the secret key $t$ you will have a vector in $q$ that hash small values $[B \times t]_q$
- **The random** $r$ is a bit vector of size $m$, $r \in \{0, 1\}^m$.
- **The message** It is a bit, yes you encrypt either $\mu \in \{0, 1\}$, and  for a vector of size $n$, $(\mu,0,...,0)$
- **Encryption** :

$$c \leftarrow (\mu,0,...,0) \cdot \frac{q}{2} + r \times B$$

- **Decryption** :

\begin{align}
\langle c,t\rangle &= \langle (\mu,0,...,0) \cdot \frac{q}{2} + r \times B ,t\rangle\\
 & = (\mu,0,...,0) \cdot \frac{q}{2} \times t + r \times B \times t \\
 & = (\mu \cdot \frac{q}{2},0,...,0) \times t + r \times B \times t \\
 & = \mu \cdot \frac{q}{2}+ r \times (B \times t)
\end{align}

remember $[B \times t]_q$  was chosen as "small" and  $r$  was a bit vector. If you consider the final integer in $\mod q$.

$$\mu \cdot \frac{q}{2} + \text{"small"}$$

The "small" in the beginning is adjusted so that $r \times B \times t$ never exceeds $q/2$.

Now, calling the MSB on the result will provide the $\mu$ since $\mu \cdot q/2$ makes the MSB 0 or 1 depending on the $\mu$.

**Correctness**

The small term is also called the error $e$ term. The correctness requires that $|e| < \lfloor q/2 \rfloor /2 $

---

**Note:** I did not go to verify the example, since $q$ is so small to work. The bounds must be carefully controlled.

The below sageMath code is working, however, one needs to tune the "small", that is left!

---

```
q = 129 # n^2 < 129 < 2n^2
R = IntegerModRing(q)
n = 10 # vector size
m = 10 # random vector size

def randSecretKey(R, size):
    v = vector(R,sample(range(q), size))
    v[0] =1
    return v

def randPublicKey(R,m,n):
    m2 = random_matrix(R,m,n)
    return m2

def randomBitVEctor(R,size):
    v = vector(R,[randint(0, 1) for i in range(size)])
    return v
    
def smallPKSK(R,m,n,sk,q):
    trials = 0
    small = false
    while not small:
        trials += 1
        inrange = true
        pk = randPublicKey(R,m,n)
        c = pk*sk
        for i in c:
            if i > 50:
               inrange = false
        if inrange == true:
            print( "number of =", trials)
            return pk

def encodeMessage(R,bit,m):
    mu = zero_vector(R,m)
    mu[0] = bit
    return mu

def encrypt(R, q, mu, r, B):

    return mu * R(64) + r * B

def decrypt(R, c, t):
    return c*t

sk = randSecretKey(R,n)
print("\nsecret key = ", sk)

pk = smallPKSK(R,m,n,sk,q)
print("\nPublic key\n")
print(pk)

pk*sk

r = randomBitVEctor(R,n)
print( "r = " , r)

mu = encodeMessage(R,1,m)
print("mu = ",mu)

c = encrypt(R, q, mu, r, pk)

print("ciphertext = ",c)

p = decrypt(R, c, sk)

print("plaintext = ",p)
Integer(p).digits(2)
```

Comment: Note: I did not go to verify the examples, since $q$ is so small to work. The bounds must be carefully controlled.

Comment: first of all thanks for answer. Please read my edit and add your opinion to your answer before i accept your answer.