# Encryption and decryption for LWE

Tags: encryption, post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, decryption, quantum-cryptography

For https://asecuritysite.com/public/lwe_ring.pdf#page=9 , could anyone explain how the encryption and decryption for LWE work ?

When I do more reading on https://summerschool-croatia.cs.ru.nl/2015/Lattice-based%20crypto.pdf#page=29 , someone told me that when decrypting we get $q/2 M + r e$. If we can bound $r e$ by $q/4$ then we can retrieve $M$ by checking if this is closer to $0$ or $q/2$.  May I ask how bounding $r e$ by $q/4$ helps?

On page 33 of a similar document, what is the purpose of the assumption on `α` ? and how to derive the expressions for this assumption and its corresponding probability?

[image: LWE]

Comment: Might insight you https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/87501/18298

Comment: @kelalaka what are `sk` and `pk` respectively in the keygen section ?

Comment: sk for the private key, pk for the public key..

Comment: @kelalaka May I ask why `v-su` equals `q/2 M + r e` ?

Answer (score 3):

> Someone told me that when decrypting we get $qM/2  + r e$. If we can
> bound $r e$ by $q/4$ then we can retrieve $M$ by checking if this is closer
> to 0 or $q/2$. May I ask how bounding $r e$ by $q/4$ helps ?

In this case, $M$ is either $0$ or $1$ and what we actually receive on decrypting is a value $d=qM/2+re\mod q$. Suppose for example that $q=10,000$, then

- $qM/2$ will be either 0 (corresponding to $M=0$) or
- It will be 5000 (corresponding to $M=1$).

If we can be sure that $|re|\le 2499$ then

- in the case $M=1$ our decryption can only lie in $[2501,7499]$ and
- in the case $M=0$ our can only lie in the ranges $[0,2499]$ and $[7501,9999]$.

These ranges do not overlap and so recovery of $M$ is unambiguous.

> On page 33 of the similar document, what is the purpose of the
> assumption on $\alpha$? and how to derive the expressions for this
> assumption and its corresponding probability?

In these slides, $\alpha$ is chosen to be the standard deviation of the discretised Gaussian from which the coefficients of $\mathbf e$ are sampled. Likewise, coefficients of $\mathbf r$ are taken to be either 0 or 1 based on independent coin-flips. This means that the value $\mathbf r\cdot\mathbf e$ is the sum of approximately $m/2$ discrete Gaussian samples, each with standard deviation $\alpha q$ and so we expect this value to be distributed roughly Gaussian with standard deviation $\sqrt{m/2}\alpha q$. By the choice $\alpha=o(1/\sqrt m\log n)$, the standard deviation of $\mathbf r\cdot\mathbf e$ will be $o(q/\sqrt{\log n})$ and so the chance of observing a value of absolute value greater than $q/4$ will be bounded by the chance of observing a Gaussian outside of $\sqrt{\log n}/o(1)$-standard deviations. Standard tail estimates for the Gaussian distribution then apply to give the bound $n^{-1/o(1)}$ on the probability of such an event.

Comment: you did not explain how the choice of `α` expression is being derived ?

Comment: I do not understand your last two sentences of your answer

Comment: What does `n^(−1/o(1))` means ?

Comment: @kevin for $\alpha$, practically everyone uses the [lattice estimator](https://github.com/malb/lattice-estimator). Increasing $\alpha$ yields better security, but can make protocols less efficient, so there's a tradeoff.

Comment: Regarding the last two sentences, it's a (brief summary of) a theoretical (probabilistic) calculation underlying precisely how high we can set $\alpha$ without it making decryption start failing. If we set $\alpha$ too high, we both get "more security", and incorrect constructions (unless we also raise $q$, making things less efficient).

Comment: @Mark however, someone told me that I need to use [tail estimation](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2021/11/05/normal-tail-estimate/) to derive the relationship between standard deviation and `q/4`.  Do you know how to do this ? if yes, could you show it ?

Comment: @kevin, yes I know how to do this. I would be happy to give an answer, but it is considered "bad form" to give in-depth answers to unrelated questions in comments (it makes the answers harder to find via the site's search interface). If you open a new question, and then post a link to it here afterwords, I'd be happy to give an answer.

Comment: " value r⋅e is the sum of approximately m/2 discrete Gaussian samples,"  <-- why `m/2` ?

Comment: @Mark  "calculation underlying precisely how high we can set α without it making decryption start failing" --> See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/102178/value-bound-of-r%e2%8b%85e-for-lwe-decryption-correctness